# compoundjs routes regex

Tags: regex, node.js, express, compoundjs

Can we use regexp in routes map? I am creating a simple file browser. I have this route set in my `/config/routes.js`:

```
map.all('/assets/:folder.:format?', 'assets#index');
```

But the folder parameter could be (for example) `Images/Logos`, so I am interested if I can use regular expression for one.

In my ROR project I was able to solve the similar issue with the help of router' `:contrains` parameter:

```
match 'applications/:store/:platform/:identifier/:filename' => 'assets#direct_download',
    :constraints => {
      :store => /[\w.-]+/,
      :platform => /[\w.-]+/,
      :identifier => /[\w.-]+/,
      :filename => /.+/
    }
```

I was not able to find any examples. So I will be thankfull if somebody could clarify this for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this syntax:

```
map.all(new RegExp('^\/assets\/(.*)$'), 'assets#index');
```

And then capture the parameters with its index (starting from `0` - the whole string is ignored, **unlike** the `preg_match` or similar functions):

```
// app/controllers/assets_controller.js
console.log(params[0]);
```

Comment: Ok, do you know, may be there is posibility to have named parameters somehow?

Comment: @jaromudr you could modify the `railway-routes` nodejs module by your own to fix that. I see no sanity in the code that handles regexpy-routes now: https://github.com/1602/railway-routes/blob/master/lib/railway_routes.js#L53